# grab a number after file extension

Tags: linux, bash

I have gigabytes of files with the following naming convention:

```
H__Flights_SCP_Log_Analysis_Log_Store_Extracted_File_Store_Aircraft_023_Logs_06Apr2021_164418_dtd_slotb_MDN_Gateway_Logs_audit_audit.log.1
```

The number at the end (`1`) is important and I need to grab it. Currently my code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#this grabs all the log files in the folder that will be converted and places it in a variable

files=$(find ./ -name "*.log*")

#I iterate through each file in files to convert each one

for file in $files
do

   #this grabs the file name except the file extension and places it in a variable
   name=${file%.*}
   #this converts the file and places it in a file with the same name plus a csv extension
   ausearch -if "file" --format csv>>$name.csv
done
```

This works fine to convert the logs and name them except that it does not grab the number at the end of the file extension. How could I grab that?

Answer (score 2):

Continuing with OPs current use of parameter substitution ...

```
$ file='H__Flights_SCP_Log_Analysis_Log_Store_Extracted_File_Store_Aircraft_023_Logs_06Apr2021_164418_dtd_slotb_MDN_Gateway_Logs_audit_audit.log.1'

$ mynum="${file##*.}"
$ echo "${mynum}"
1

# or

$ mynum="${file//*./}"
$ echo "${mynum}"
1
```